# Express response body after send

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express I would like to audit  response after I send it

```
var app = express();
app.use(audit.auditRequest); // working fine
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressValidator({
 customValidators: validations.customValidators,
 customSanitizers: sanitizers.customSanitizers
}));
app.use(auth.authenticate);
app.use('/myPath', myPathHandler);
app.use(errorHandler.handleErrors);
**app.use(audit.auditResponse);**
```

errorHandler, for example, looks like this:

```
...
res.status(500).send({ message : "abc", code: 5010, description : "def" });
next(); // call audit middleware
```

and then audit middleware looks like this:

```
...      
auditModule.auditResponse = function auditResponse(req, res, next) {
      auditLogger.info('Response', res.body); 
      // but res.body is undefined
};
...
```

Any idea why?

Comment: did you mean `req.body`?

Comment: No, I need to log the response I send to the user

Comment: Put the full code here.

Comment: added more code, thanks

Comment: Added an answer should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As much as I'm aware response body isn't just available as easily as property on response.

So : `res.body` isn't going to work. So, I have a work-around. We can catch data from response write, accumulate it and add it into res.body manually. Inject this as a middleware so it will work. Pls note it should be injected before any `.compress()`.

Inject as middleware (this is in ES6 & will work in Node.js directly, but if you want I'll change the answer to ES5):

```
server.use((req, res, next) => {
    const original_write = res.write,
        original_end = res.end,
        chunks = [];
    res.write = function(chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
        original_write.apply(res, arguments);
    };
    res.end = function(chunk) {
        if (chunk)
            chunks.push(chunk);
        res.body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8');
        original_end.apply(res, arguments);
    };
    next();
});
```

Now you can happily use `res.body` after your you send the response. :D

Note: *the `res.body` will be a utf8 encoded String. Parse it back to json if it was an object.*

Comment: I'll try this out! I also found a suggestion to add an attribute on the res object- res.bodyForAudit = bodyToSend and then reading it when reaching the middleware. What do you think?

Comment: you can, but you have to read it in the same way as above. Only reason I wrote a more generic soln is so that someone else could use it in the future for a different purpose.

Comment: Would this work if the data is written in the response object with .send/.json and other (if any) functions that send the response ? For example `res.send("Hello World");`

Answer (score -5):

Try `req.body` instead of `res.body`.

Comment: See my edit, I want to read the body of a response after I sent it